# Please put '[tag]' behind titles on Android

Tags: feature-request, android-app, on-hold

On the main site, on can see `[on hold]` or `[duplicate]` or alike tags behind a title in the question overview, which determines the question is not open for answers.

However, when looking on the Android app, this does not occur. For example, this is a closed question:

[image: duplicate question]

...this is the overview (with that question as topmost) in the Android app:

[image: overview on app]

...and this is the view on the (mobile) site:

[image: overview on site]

We can clearly see the question has been closed as a duplicate, and while the site shows `[duplicate]` in the title, the app doesn't.
As multiline question titles are clearly not a problem, can we have these few characters behind them as well?

Comment: I'm not sure bracketed text is the best possible indicator for the app UI, but I agree that something is needed!

Comment: At least it would be consistent, and therefore probably most recognisable.

Comment: Ironically, I didn't realize this question was closed as a duplicate when I saw it in the app, even though the request is [status-completed]. I thought that [duplicate] was part of the question's original title :p